# Ubuntu 16.04: libclang 6 cannot be installed

Tags: 16.04, package-management, dependencies, synaptic, clang

I am currently trying to install doxygen, which has an unmet dependency libclang.so.6. I followed [these instructions](https://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/k/how-to-install-latest-clang-5.0-on-ubuntu-16.04-xenial-wsl.html) for installing this package, but it has its own dependencies.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
clang-6.0 : Depends: libjsoncpp1 (>= 1.7.4) but 1.7.2-1 is to be installed
         Depends: libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libgcc-7-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libobjc-7-dev but it is not installable
         Depends: libclang-common-6.0-dev (= 1:6.0.1~svn331815-1~exp1~20180509123840.80) but 1:6.0.1~svn331722-1~exp1~20180508135726.78 is to be installed
         Depends: libclang1-6.0 (= 1:6.0.1~svn331815-1~exp1~20180509123840.80) but 1:6.0.1~svn331722-1~exp1~20180508135726.78 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have tried installing each of these, both using apt-get and synaptic, but they all are either unavailable or not available in the correct version. How can I find and install the correct versions of each of these dependencies?

Comment: @Danibix Yes.  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  [long list]
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 6 not to upgrade.`

Comment: @Danibix Yes, and I get the same list of unmet dependencies. Is there a particular directory file I need to do this in? I'm doing it in the same directory as the doxygen executable.

Comment: `Depends: libstdc++-7-dev but it is not installable` : You are trying to install Ubuntu 17.10 or  18.04 packages.

Answer (score 1):

I just upgraded to 18.04 and it worked.